# Springboot app SMTP sending emails works just on localhost

Tags: java, spring-boot, smtp

Hi i am trying to send email from my springboot app and it work perfect, but just on localhost. When i try it put on vps, i get this error, i see that my vps normal connect  and authenticate to SMTP server, but in the end for some reason sending fail. I have no firewall on my vps, have anyone idea, why is this happening? Thanks!

```
DEBUG: setDebug: Jakarta Mail version 2.0.1
DEBUG: getProvider() returning jakarta.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
DEBUG SMTP: need username and password for authentication
DEBUG SMTP: protocolConnect returning false, host=wes1-smtp.wedos.net, user=martin.lepic@email.cz, password=<null>
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "wes1-smtp.wedos.net", port 587, isSSL false
220 wes1-so2.wedos.net ESMTP Postfix - S.T.A.N.D.A. postak OUT
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "wes1-smtp.wedos.net", port: 587
EHLO 5575e5731be3
250-wes1-so2.wedos.net
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 104857600
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "104857600"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "VRFY", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ETRN", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "STARTTLS", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "DSN", arg ""
STARTTLS
220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
EHLO 5575e5731be3
250-wes1-so2.wedos.net
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 104857600
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "104857600"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "VRFY", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ETRN", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "PLAIN LOGIN"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "DSN", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: protocolConnect login, host=wes1-smtp.wedos.net, user=martin.lepic@email.cz, password=<non-null>
DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate using mechanisms: LOGIN PLAIN DIGEST-MD5 NTLM XOAUTH2
DEBUG SMTP: Using mechanism LOGIN
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN command trace suppressed
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN succeeded
DEBUG SMTP: use8bit false
MAIL FROM:<martin.lepic@email.cz>
250 2.1.0 Ok
RCPT TO:<martin.lepic@email.cz>
250 2.1.5 Ok
DEBUG SMTP: Verified Addresses
DEBUG SMTP:   martin.lepic@email.cz
DATA
354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
Date: Tue, 30 May 2023 18:08:21 +0000 (UTC)
From: martin.lepic@email.cz
To: martin.lepic@email.cz
Message-ID: <1085117917.0.1685470101618@5575e5731be3>
Subject: Email Subject
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

QUIT
DEBUG SMTP: exception reading response, THROW:
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedRead(NioSocketImpl.java:283)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implRead(NioSocketImpl.java:309)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.read(NioSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$1.read(NioSocketImpl.java:803)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketInputStream.read(Socket.java:966)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:478)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.readHeader(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:472)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.bytesInCompletePacket(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:70)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readApplicationRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1455)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:1059)
    at com.sun.mail.util.TraceInputStream.read(TraceInputStream.java:102)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:244)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:263)
    at com.sun.mail.util.LineInputStream.readLine(LineInputStream.java:100)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.readServerResponse(SMTPTransport.java:2456)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.close(SMTPTransport.java:1396)
    at org.simplejavamail.mailer.internal.util.TransportRunner.runOnSessionTransport(TransportRunner.java:74)
    at org.simplejavamail.mailer.internal.util.TransportRunner.sendMessage(TransportRunner.java:51)
    at org.simplejavamail.mailer.internal.SendMailClosure.executeClosure(SendMailClosure.java:69)
    at org.simplejavamail.mailer.internal.AbstractProxyServerSyncingClosure.run(AbstractProxyServerSyncingClosure.java:56)
    at org.simplejavamail.mailer.internal.MailerImpl.sendMail(MailerImpl.java:363)
    at org.simplejavamail.mailer.internal.MailerImpl.sendMail(MailerImpl.java:348)
    at cz.digikyblik.main.services.EmailService.simpleMail(EmailService.java:63)
    at cz.digikyblik.main.services.BucketService.lambda$createBucket$0(BucketService.java:79)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1804)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.exec(CompletableFuture.java:1796)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:373)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1182)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1655)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1622)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:165)
org.simplejavamail.mailer.internal.MailerException: Failed to send email [ID: '<1085117917.0.1685470101618@5575e5731be3>'], reason: Unknown error
    at org.simplejavamail.mailer.internal.SendMailClosure.handleException(SendMailClosure.java:85)
    at org.simplejavamail.mailer.internal.SendMailClosure.executeClosure(SendMailClosure.java:76)
    at org.simplejavamail.mailer.internal.AbstractProxyServerSyncingClosure.run(AbstractProxyServerSyncingClosure.java:56)
    at org.simplejavamail.mailer.internal.MailerImpl.sendMail(MailerImpl.java:363)
    at org.simplejavamail.mailer.internal.MailerImpl.sendMail(MailerImpl.java:348)
    at cz.digikyblik.main.services.EmailService.simpleMail(EmailService.java:63)
    at cz.digikyblik.main.services.BucketService.lambda$createBucket$0(BucketService.java:79)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1804)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.exec(CompletableFuture.java:1796)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:373)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1182)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1655)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1622)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:165)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Provider for jakarta.activation.spi.MailcapRegistryProvider cannot be found
    at jakarta.activation.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:90)
    at jakarta.activation.MailcapCommandMap.getImplementation(MailcapCommandMap.java:696)
    at jakarta.activation.MailcapCommandMap.loadFile(MailcapCommandMap.java:284)
    at jakarta.activation.MailcapCommandMap.<init>(MailcapCommandMap.java:154)
    at jakarta.activation.CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap(CommandMap.java:60)
    at jakarta.activation.DataHandler.getCommandMap(DataHandler.java:128)
    at jakarta.activation.DataHandler.getDataContentHandler(DataHandler.java:590)
    at jakarta.activation.DataHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:290)
    at jakarta.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:1670)
    at jakarta.mail.internet.MimeMessage.writeTo(MimeMessage.java:1888)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1300)
    at org.simplejavamail.mailer.internal.util.TransportRunner.lambda$sendMessage$0(TransportRunner.java:53)
    at org.simplejavamail.mailer.internal.util.TransportRunner.runOnSessionTransport(TransportRunner.java:73)
    at org.simplejavamail.mailer.internal.util.TransportRunner.sendMessage(TransportRunner.java:51)
    at org.simplejavamail.mailer.internal.SendMailClosure.executeClosure(SendMailClosure.java:69)
    ... 12 more
    Suppressed: jakarta.mail.MessagingException: Exception reading response;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.readServerResponse(SMTPTransport.java:2476)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.close(SMTPTransport.java:1396)
        at org.simplejavamail.mailer.internal.util.TransportRunner.runOnSessionTransport(TransportRunner.java:74)
        ... 14 more
    Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedRead(NioSocketImpl.java:283)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implRead(NioSocketImpl.java:309)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.read(NioSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$1.read(NioSocketImpl.java:803)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketInputStream.read(Socket.java:966)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:478)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.readHeader(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:472)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.bytesInCompletePacket(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:70)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readApplicationRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1455)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:1059)
        at com.sun.mail.util.TraceInputStream.read(TraceInputStream.java:102)
        at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:244)
        at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:263)
        at com.sun.mail.util.LineInputStream.readLine(LineInputStream.java:100)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.readServerResponse(SMTPTransport.java:2456)
        ... 16 more
```

EDIT
Here is code, but like i said, it works normal when i run it on localhost and its send it immediately.

```
public void simpleMail() {
    Email email = EmailBuilder.startingBlank()
            .from("noreply@digikyblik.cz")
            .to("martin.lepic@email.cz")
            .withSubject("Email Subject")
            .withPlainText("Email Body")
            .buildEmail();

    Mailer mailer = MailerBuilder
            .withSMTPServer("wes1-smtp.wedos.net", 587, "mail", "pass")
            .withTransportStrategy(TransportStrategy.SMTP_TLS)
            .buildMailer();

    mailer.getSession().setDebug(true);

    try {
        mailer.sendMail(email);
    } catch (MailException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Where is the single dot on a line by itself that signals the end of the message?  It looks like your code never sent that, so it eventually timed out waiting for a response code that was never going to arrive.

Answer (score 1):

Some VPS providers require you to configure the security network for outbound network communication. In some cases, you may need to configure outbound rules to allow communication from your Spring Boot application to the SMTP server and allow sending of emails.